# Can the present perfect and the past perfect be interchangeable in certain contexts?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Could you tell me if the present perfect and the past perfect can be interchangeable in certain contexts? For example in the context below Pam from The Office used the past perfect where the present perfect is seemingly can be used.

> Ryan: Um, also, little tip, never shake the baby.
>
> Jim: Sorry, just to be clear, you’re saying do NOT shake the baby.
>
> Ryan: Don’t shake the baby. Um, a lot of times, parents get frustrated
> ’cause the baby’s crying and they shake the baby. And you got to, um,
> you can’t do that.
>
> Pam: Don’t shake our baby?
>
> Ryan: Yeah.
>
> Pam: Okay. **I’d never heard that before**. So, thank you.

Could Pan say *I have never heard that before* in the context without any change in meaning?

Comment: Similar to your earlier question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/235645/i-had-never-vs-i-have-never-when-talking-about-a-first-time-event-in-the-past ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. This context is different, though. There is no reference to the past in this context, which makes it hard for me figure it out.

Comment: People say 'I hadn't heard it before' meaning 'until you told me just now' - so the sense is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! So both the present perfect and the past perfect are equally correct and natural, right?

Comment: You hear both versions; there seems to be some debate about which is right. https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-had-never-heard-vs-i-have-never-heard.2486366/

Comment: Thanks for the link! As a native speaker of English, I would like to know if both sound natural to you.

Comment: Yes. I would probably use _had_ for a fact someone had just told me.